# Is there a way to accept UAC prompts with QTP?

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, uac, qtp, gui-testing

I have created an automated test that needs to run an executable file (in this instance, an uninstall script). This causes Windows 7 to display a User Account Control prompt that needs to be accepted before the QTP test can continue.

As it stands, I had to lower UAC to the "do not dim my desktop" level in order to even add the dialog to the Object Repository. I tried recording clicking the Yes button, but QTP didn't notice my actions, so I had to manually add the object.

Even then, when I add the line `Dialog("User Account Control").WinButton("Yes").Click`, I receive `Unspecified Error` from QTP.

**Edit:**
I've also tried using the code below to click on an arbitrary point on the screen (where the "Yes" button just happens to be).

```vb
Set dr = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
dr.MouseClick 1030, 550, LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON
```

The good news is the cursor lands right on the "Yes" button, unfortunately the click doesn't work.

**Is there any way for QTP to accept the UAC prompt, without disabling UAC altogether?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what QTP is, but the problem is that it is trying to click buttons it is not allowed to.

Windows prevents applications from programmatically clicking on the **Consent** dialog. This is done to prevent what is known as a [*Shatter Attack*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack). Also, if code was allowed to see and click the UAC consent dialog, malware could click the UAC prompt itself.

There is a mechanism to allow programs to declare that they need to be able to drive the user interface; allowing software to see, and click on, the UAC dialog. It is a serious enough security risk that the application needs to:

- be digitally signed
- be run from Program Files

## Declare that you need the right

If you ask the developers of QTP to alter their assembly manifest; turning on the `**uiAccess=true**` option:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 

    <!-- Disable Windows Vista UAC compatability heuristics -->
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo> 
</assembly>
```

and then they digitally sign the QTP executable, and then install it in **Program Files**, then it will be able to click the UAC dialog.

## Bonus Reading

From Chris Jackson's [*Using the uiAccess attribute of requestedExecutionLevel to Improve Applications Providing Remote Control of the Desktop*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2009/10/15/using-the-uiaccess-attribute-of-requestedexecutionlevel-to-improve-applications-providing-remote-control-of-the-desktop.aspx):

> Now, most people don’t really understand what this is for, and the UAC manifest is typically just a copy/paste affair. But it pays for the remote desktop developer to pay attention to it. For any regular piece of software, you generally want to stay away from it – it’s dangerous, and sidesteps a significant security feature (UIPI). But if you are remoting the desktop, it’s precisely what you want – you need to be able to see everything!
>
> It’s dangerous enough, in fact, that **we won’t allow you to set it without digitally signing your application**. By default, you also **have to have it installed in a secure location** (such as Program Files).